# R boot::boot(): function which returns mean and the used samples

Tags: r

I'm using the `boot()` function from the boot package to bootstrap means from a population. The used function is:

```
boot_mean <- function(data, i){
  
  ds_m <- data[i]
  return(mean(ds_m))
  
}
```

Works like charm but now I want to adapt the `boot_mean` function so that I can get the samples which lead to the mean too. I tried:

```
library('boot')

boot_mean <- function(data, i){
  
  ds_m <- data[i]
  ds_m_mean <- mean(ds_m)
  rlist <- list("means" = ds_m_mean, "data" = ds_m)
  return(rlist)
  
}

dummy_data <- rnorm(500)
dummy_boot <- boot(dummy_data, boot_mean, R = 1000)
```

Which results in an error:

> Error in t.star[r, ] <- res[[r]] :    incorrect number of subscripts
> on matrix

What's wrong here? How can I get the corresponding dataset to the bootstrapped mean?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the documentation `?boot`, describing the `statistic` argument.

> A function which when applied to data returns a **vector** containing the statistic(s) of interest. ...

The `boot()` function only wants to deal with functions that output a single vector. Modifying your code to return a `list` of two elements means it won't work anymore. There's actually a little interesting oddity in R and the `boot()` function which means the code *almost* works if you set `R=1` in the `boot()` call, but it's still wrong.

Fortunately for your purpose, the authors have already programmed the useful `boot.array()` function. It outputs a matrix with `R` rows and `nrow(data)` columns, indicating either how many times the jth individual was sampled for the ith bootstrap, or the indices of the sampled individuals. Getting the bootstrapped datasets can easily be found by selecting those individuals from the data. This can take a little while.

```r
dats <- lapply(1:nrow(boot.array(dummy_boot)), 
    FUN = function(x) dummy_data[boot.array(dummy_boot, indices = TRUE)[x, ]])
```

If you have multiple columns of data you should add `, , drop = FALSE`

```r
dats <- lapply(1:nrow(boot.array(dummy_boot)), 
    FUN = function(x) dummy_data[boot.array(dummy_boot, indices = TRUE)[x, ], , drop = FALSE])
```